# how to write a Cloud Function for send email using SendGrid

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am trying to send email using sendGrid (In my mobile application). So i wrote a cloud function and deployed it into firebase.(using this,Visit https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular4-transactional-email-with-cloud-functions-and-sendgrid/).

it was uploaded to firebase. But, when i try to send post request(Using postman`{"to":"user1@gmail.com","from":"duser253@gmail.com","subject":"test-email","content":"content"}`), in firebase log shows some errors

```
SendGridError: Response error
at /user_code/node_modules/sendgrid/lib/sendgrid.js:104:23
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/sendgrid/node_modules/sendgrid-rest/lib/client.js:124:7)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at connectErrorNT (net.js:1040:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
  message: 'Response error',
  response: 
   { statusCode: 500,
     body: 
      { message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443',
        name: 'Error',
        stack: 'Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443\n    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)\n    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)' },
     headers: {} }
```

Comment: On which payment plan are you? The free "Spark" plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services. You need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan, since Sendgrid is not a Google-owned service. See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: I changed the payment plan. Now it shows another error.    (SendGridError: Response error
    at /user_code/node_modules/sendgrid/lib/sendgrid.js:104:23
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/sendgrid/node_modules/sendgrid-rest/lib/client.js:112:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback)

Comment: It's working @RenaudTarnec.Thanks a lot

Comment: Good! I will therefore add an answer based on my comment. You may accept it.

Comment: Thanx bro. it is really helped to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be on the "Flame" or "Blaze" pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

Since Sendgrid is not a Google-owned service, you need to switch to the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan.