# request(...).then is not a function error when making a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a firebase function that makes a HTTP POST request whenever a new document is created.

This is my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const request = require("request");


exports.sendMessage = functions.firestore.document('comms/{comms}').onCreate((snap, context) => {


  const newValue = snap.data();

  if (newValue) {

    //const email = newValue.email;
    const msg = newValue.msg;


    return request({
      uri: "url",
      method: 'POST',
      body: msg,
      json: true,
      resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }).then((response: { statusCode: number; }) => {
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.statusCode}`);
      }
      console.log('SUCCESS! Posted', msg);
    });

  }

 return Promise 
});
```

```
Error received:
```

TypeError: request(...).then is not a function
    at exports.sendMessage.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/srv/lib/index.js:25:12)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:127:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at 
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: request is not Promised based

Comment: if you want to be Promise base use util package

Comment: Try the request-promise module if you want to deal with promises instead of callbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request` supports callback interfaces natively **but does not return a promise**, which is what you must do within a Cloud Function.

This is explained in the official Firebase video series here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/. In particular watch the three videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises" (Parts 2 & 3 especially focus on background triggered Cloud Functions, but it really worth watching Part 1 before).

You could use `request-promise` (https://github.com/request/request-promise) and the `rp()` method which "returns a regular Promises/A+ compliant promise". You would then adapt your code as follows:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const rp = require('request-promise');


exports.sendMessage = functions.firestore.document('comms/{comms}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const newValue = snap.data();

    if (newValue) {

        const msg = newValue.msg;


        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: '....',
            body: msg,
            json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
        };

        return rp(options)
        .then(parsedBody => {
            // POST succeeded...
            console.log('SUCCESS! Posted', msg);
            return null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // POST failed...
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        });

    } else {
        return null;
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Comment: Tried without the if statement and received the error:   name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN hooks.slack.com:443',          it throws this error because I'm on a free plan on Firebase?

Comment: @AndreiEnache  "it throws this error because I'm on a free plan on Firebase? " -> yes, most probably if you query a service that is not Google onwned. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925963/how-to-write-a-cloud-function-for-send-email-using-sendgrid/52942121#52942121

Answer (score 1):

request module doesn't return a Promise instead try using a callback function for response.

```
    return request({
  uri: "url",
  method: 'POST',
  body: msg,
  json: true,
  resolveWithFullResponse: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As in the documentation already mention you need to pass the callback to your request

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

If you want to chain your request you can use pipe

```
request
  .get('url/img.png')
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png'
  })
  .pipe(request.put('url'))
```

If you want to use promise you can use [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

rp('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function (htmlString) {
        // Process html...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Crawling failed...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `request` module work on callbacks only, If you want to make `Promisify` you need to do like this

```
const request = require('request');

const webService = {};

webService.callApi = (url, bodyObj, method) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      method: method || 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: bodyObj,
      json: true,
    };
    // Error Handler
    const errorMessge = { code: 500, error: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR' };

    request(options, (error, response, resBody) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(errorMessge);
      } else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return reject(errorMessge);
      }
      return resolve(resBody);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = webService;
```