# Firestore function .onCreate trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am sending a notification using `.onCreate` on a collection.

My collection is `tasks`. When new task is given, I need to send a notification to the assigned person.

Do I need to save `token` of this assigned person?  I can only fetch those values which are getting saved in document. The value of `token` is in `users` collection.

Is there a way to use `.where` condition in functions ?

My code so far [saving token of assigned person in `assignTo` field with every new task entry]::

```
    .document('todos/{todosId}')
    .onCreate(
        async (snapshot: { data: () => { (): any; new(): any; token: any; assignTo: any; text: any; name: any; profilePicUrl: any; }; }) => {

          // Notification details.
          const text = snapshot.data();
          const payload = {
            notification: {
            title: text.name,
             body: 'Notification body',
             icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png',
             click_action: `https://google.com`,
            }
          }; 

     const subscriber =   text.token;
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload)
  });
```

Is `.where` condition possible ? like,

> collections 'users' get `token` where `assignTo` == `dwqhdiu78798u`

### Edit

As guided here is my code, but function gave error

```
    //  const subscriber = "evGBnI_klVQYSBIPMqJbx8:APA91bEV5xOEbPwF4vBJ7mHrOskCTpTRJx0cQrZ_uxa-QH8HLomXdSYixwRIvcA2AuBRh4B_2DDaY8hvj-TsFJG_Hb6LJt9sgbPrWkI-eo0Xtx2ZKttbIuja4NqajofmjgnubraIOb4_"; 
    const query = admin.firestore().collection('Students').where('Name', '==', 'caca');
    const querySnapshot = await query.get();
    const subscriber = querySnapshot.doc.data().token;
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload)
  });
```

Screenshot attached:

[image]

Error in function:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question, is "In a Cloud Function, can I fetch Firestore data through a `Query` containing a [`where()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#where) clause", the answer is yes.

You should use the Admin SDK, like you do for sending the notification, as follows:

```
const query = admin.firestore().collection('users').where('assignTo', '==', 'dwqhdiu78798u');
const querySnapshot = await query.get();
//....
```

---

### Update following your comment and update

You get a error on the following line (in the code added to your question):

```
const subscriber = querySnapshot.doc.data().token;
```

This is because a `QuerySnapshot` does not have a `doc` property. The `QuerySnapshot` contains one or more DocumentSnapshots. You should either use the `docs` array or use `forEach()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question with the screenshot of `db`, the `code` i tried, it gives `error in function`, added screenshot of error too.

Comment: all working, in logs i see this message - `Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions` , Does this mean i cannot call any external api like for sms or email ??

Comment: You need to be in the Blaze plan, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52942121/3371862